# Can you insert jquery into a php file?

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I have the following .php file:

```html
<div class="excerpt">
  <?php get_the_excerpt();?>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".excerpt").hide();
  });
</script>
```

I want to hide the div class "excerpt" through jQuery. Unfortunately, the code doesn't do anything and I do not understand where I went wrong. Is it even possible to use jQuery in php?

Comment: Your code works fine - as you can see in the snippet I edited in to your question. If it's not working for you, check the console for errors

Comment: it should work.

Comment: even if we don't have the excerpt, I replaced that line with a simple echo, and it works just fine!

Comment: <?php echo get_the_excerpt();?>

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan There is no error message, it just doesn't hide the content and I dont really understand why.

Comment: Is the element in the Dom what the page loads?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Not sure if I fully understand the questions, but the code is displayed when I inspect the element.

Comment: okay, when I open the customizer in wordpress it works suddenly although I do not put anything into the customizer. Is the problem that I am using a local host maybe?

Comment: Try jQuery instead of $ jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".excerpt").hide();
  });

Comment: @BhAvikGajjar this actually worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

identifier `$` will usually won't be enabled by default in wordpress like cms

you have to use identifier `jQuery`

inorder to make identifier `$` work, you can try this

```
(function($){
    // inside this scope, $ can be used
    $(document).ready(function(){

        // other scripts

    });
})(jQuery);
```